# Instalación local firmada de app no se actualiza desde Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Hace ya como cinco días subí una nueva versión de mi aplicación a `Gloogle Play Store`, digamos las versión 1.5.
Ahora mismo mis usuarios y yo tenemos la versión 1.4 que la firmé e instale directamente a los dispositivos sin pasar el `Play Store`.

Ahora intento acceder a `Gloogle Play Store` para actualizar la versión desde mi dispositivo pero me sale el botón de `Abrir` no el de `actualizar` pero si bajo para buscar el número de la versión en la descripción me aparece la 1.5.

Si accedo a mi consola del `Play Store` aparece la versión 1.5 y todo aparentemente correcto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo estoy haciendo pruebas con una Galaxy Tab y no se actualiza

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la lista de dispositivos me sale como compatible
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hace dos horas subí una nueva versión pero sigue todo igual, no se actualizan y cuando abro la app en Gloogle play Store me sale "abrir" o "desinstalar"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí podéis ver la versiones reales en producción, los dispositivos no actualizan desde la versión 3.1.4.7

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya no se que hacer ni que revisar. ¿Alguien me puede dar alguna pista o idea de que puede estar pasando?

Comment: ¿No manipulaste nada sobre las versiones en el `gradle`? ¿Tienes la sincronización activada en tu cuenta de Google en el dispositivo?

Comment: manda captura, de la información de tu APP en tu dispositivo, para ver que versión dice

Comment: @A.Cedano si esta activada la sincronización . Nada del Gradle no cambie nada :(

Comment: @A.Cedano solo cambié la versionCode
y el versionName

Comment: Lo cambiaste a un valor superior al anterior, supongo... Revisa que la App no tenga ningún tipo de restricción en la configuración de tu dispositivo. Sería interesante que tuvieras la oportunidad de instalar la App en un dispositivo donde no exista para ver qué versión se instalaría. ¿No habrás creado una nueva App en Google Play al intentar subirla, de modo que sean dos Apps distintas? Otra cosa que puedes intentar es limpiar el caché y los datos de tu App en los ajustes y verificar que no tienes la versión debug instalada en tu dispositivo.

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he revisado todo, no no he creado una nueva app. Voy a probar lo del cache. He mandado una incidencia a Google Play a ver si me responden... gracias por las ideas

Comment: Bien, esperamos la solución final para ver lo que ha ocurrido. Saludos.

Comment: Al publicar una actualización, se pide el porcentaje de dispositivos a los que desplegarlo. Es posible que no pusieras el 100%

Comment: @Pikoh añado más datos a la pregunta

Comment: No habrás cambiado el nombre de paquete de la app...? Y el `gradle` ?

Comment: @msabate Estoy revisando el manifest, en el gradle cambio el nombre de la versión y el número de versión

Comment: @JoCuTo a ver si [esto](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113476?hl=es) te sirve, aunque lo mejor sería ponerte en contacto con Google

Comment: Si vas al Panel de la Version en el developer console, te pone Lanzamiento 100% publicada?

Comment: si 100% publicada

Comment: En la captura pone hace dos horas...has probado ahora a ver si te aparece ya la actualizacion en google play?

Comment: Si acabo de mirarlo y nada :(

Comment: Si nos enlazas la app en google play,podemos mirar que versión nos aparece a nosotros

Comment: cuando publicas la actualización en google play, mantienes el apk anterior o lo eliminas en la creación de versiones?

Comment: @CarlosQuintero pues honestamente no lo se , pero creo que no se borra por que en el historial aparecen. He puesto una nueva captura en la pregunta

Comment: @JoCuTo ¿aún no has resuelto esto?, ¿que lenguaje tiene configurado tu dispositivo? ¿La que instalaste no tiene un versionCode mayor?

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys ->  Español españa

Comment: @Jorgesys crees que puede ser por haber instalado la app firmada directamente a los dispositivos sin pasar por Google Play y después subir una nueva versión

Comment: @JoCuTo si instalaste la app directamente en los dispositivos esta más que claro que no va a tomar las actualizaciones desde la play, debes realizar la instalación desde la PlayStore, des-instala la app y reinstala desde la play y prueba de nuevo

Comment: @JoCuTo actualmente se puede actualizar desde la google play si tu generaste un .apk y lo instalaste pero hay ciertas, restricciones. Quiero preguntarte, ¿El .apk lo generaste con el mismo keystore? ¿Como obtuviste el .apk es el que se genero en el folder outputs?

Comment: ¿El .apk lo generaste con el mismo keystore? No use .Keystore, use el mismo .jks para todos las apks
¿Como obtuviste el .apk es el que se genero en el folder outputs?build->generated signed apk-> selecion mi .jks , alias y password, builtType release,  el apk se generó en el escritorio correctamente

Comment: @Jorgesys pues quizás sea ese el problema, estoy haciendo una prueba y es cierto no puedo actualizar una versión después de haberla instalada(firmada) en un dispositivo sin pasar por Google Play . Dices que se puede actualizar ,con restricciones, pero no veo la forma  lo puedes poner , por favor como respuesta a la pregunta, estoy seguro que puede ayudar a más gente con el mismo problema

Comment: "sin pasar por Google Play" si puedes actualizar, voy a agregar una respuesta en base a lo que comentas.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys !! creo que puede ayudar a mucha gente , hay mucha confusión al respecto. Voy a editar el titulo de la pregunta para que sea más especifico. Nuevamente muchas gracias

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys alguna idea por fa??