# Diferencias entre .jks y .keystore

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

Estoy firmando mi app y subiéndola a `Google Play Store`  con un

> .jks

y estoy teniendo problemas por que no se actualiza en los dispositivos, por otro lado también veo que se puede firmar con

> .keystore

Mi pregunta es:¿Que diferencia hay entre `.jks`  y `.keystore`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8985685/difference-between-keystore-file-and-jks-file?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Tu problema no esta en el modo de firmarlos, si no como estas manejando las versiones tanto en el **grandle** como en **PlayConsole**

Comment: @CarlosQuintero y como sabes como lo estoy manejando en gradle y PlayConsole?

Comment: @JoCuTo porque son la única forma de que tu app no se actualice o informe de nuevas actualizaciones en los dispositivos instalados, hay una buena cantidad de pasos que podrían estar saliendo mal sin que te des cuenta, podrías publicar mas información y así ayudarte mejor, en cuanto a tu pregunta ambos son almacenes de claves, puedes utilizar uno o el otro para la firma de tu app, lo que si debes recordar, es que la firma no puede cambiar cuando ya publicaste tu app

Comment: @CarlosQuintero gracias, tengo otro hilo abierto aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/160943/no-se-actualiza-app-desde-google-play-store

Answer (score 0):

En última instancia, .keystore y .jks son solo extensiones de archivo: depende de usted nombrar sus archivos con sensatez.

Algunas aplicaciones usan un archivo de almacén de claves almacenado en `$HOME/.keystore`: generalmente se da a entender que es un archivo JKS, ya que [JKS es el tipo de almacén de claves predeterminado en el proveedor de seguridad Sun/Oracle Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SUNProvider).

No todo el mundo usa la extensión `.jks` para los archivos `JKS`, porque está implícita como predeterminada. Recomiendo usar la extensión, solo para recordar qué tipo especificar (si es necesario).

En Java, la palabra almacén de claves puede tener cualquiera de los siguientes significados, según el contexto:

- la API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyStore.html
- un archivo (u otro mecanismo) que se puede usar para respaldar esta API
- un almacén de claves en lugar de un almacén de confianza, como se describe aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6341566/372643

Cuando se habla del archivo y el almacenamiento, esto no es realmente una instalación de almacenamiento para pares clave/valor (hay muchos otros formatos para esto). Más bien, es un contenedor para almacenar claves y certificados criptográficos (creo que algunos de ellos también pueden almacenar contraseñas). Generalmente, estos archivos están encriptados y protegidos con contraseña para no permitir que estos datos estén disponibles para personas no autorizadas.

Java usa su clase [KeyStore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#SUNProvider) y la API relacionada para hacer uso de un almacén de claves ([ya sea que esté basado en archivos o no](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157716/372643)). JKS es un formato de archivo específico de Java, pero la API también se puede usar con otros tipos de archivos, normalmente PKCS#12. Cuando desee cargar un almacén de claves, debe especificar su tipo de almacén de claves. Las extensiones convencionales serían:

- .jks para tipo "JKS"
- .p12 o .pfx para el tipo "PKCS12" (el nombre de la especificación es PKCS#12, pero el # no se usa en el nombre del tipo de almacén de claves de Java).

Además, BouncyCastle también proporciona sus implementaciones, en particular [BKS](https://www.bouncycastle.org/specifications.html) (normalmente con la extensión .bks), que se usa con frecuencia para las aplicaciones de Android.

---

Tomado de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9041012/250260) de [@Bruno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/372643/bruno)